# Add note that there is no IRC integration to the chat FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

The question of an IRC interface to chat seems to come up every few hours (at least it feels like it). E.g. a recent question: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/chats/message/89694?offset=60

Could a note be added to the FAQ saying there is no official mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea, adding it now.

Answer (score 0):

Just ask a new question, mark it faq-proposed, and it will eventually (a few months) be added.

Comment: You don't even need to ask a new question; just edit this one.  It's fairly related and there aren't really any answers to trample.